# php - Insert multiple rows via php arrays into mysql

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, text-files

I have a .txt file split into lines, and the items for each line are split into arrays log_dates and log_times. I'm trying to insert each log date and it's matching log time into my database which has log_date and log_time columns.

Access.txt

```
2014-03-16 13:57:35.089
2014-03-16 13:57:35.089
2014-03-16 13:57:35.089
2014-03-16 13:57:35.089
```

LogsModel.php

```
function __construct($db) {
    try {
        $this->db = $db;
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        exit('Database connection could not be established.');
    }
}

public function insertFileContents()
{
    $filename = 'C:/Program Files/FileMaker/FileMaker Server/Logs/Access.log';

    // Open the file
    $fp = @fopen($filename, 'r');

    // Add each line to an array
    if ($fp) {
        $lines = explode("\n", fread($fp, filesize($filename)));

        foreach($lines as $line){
            $l = explode(" ", $line);
            $log_dates[] = $l[0];
            $log_times[] = $l[1];

            $sql = ("INSERT INTO log_table VALUES (log_date, log_time) VALUES ('$log_dates', '$log_times')");

            $query = $this->db->prepare($sql);
            $query->execute();
        }

        return true;
    }

}
```

Eventually I would like to have it so every time the page is accessed the database gets updated by the Access.txt file which will continue to accumulate new rows.

Comment: You're using PDO, why aren't you using parametrized queries?

Comment: Thanks @Barmar, was just looking for something easy to get the data in. I get a SQL Syntax Error - "Warning: PDOStatement::execute(): SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'VALUES ('2014-03-16', '13:57:35.089')' at line 1 in C:\wamp\www\application\models\logsmodel.php on line 53"

Comment: `VALUES` only goes before the list of values, not before the list of column names.

Comment: Comments about my answer should be put below the answer, not the question.

Comment: @Barmar - apologies, that was stupid of me... data is being inserted now, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$log_dates` and `$log_times` shouldn't be arrays, they should be string variables:

```
    foreach($lines as $line){
        $l = explode(" ", $line);
        $log_dates = $l[0];
        $log_times = $l[1];

        $sql = ("INSERT INTO log_table (log_date, log_time) VALUES ('$log_dates', '$log_times')");

        $query = $this->db->prepare($sql);
        $query->execute();
    }
```

You also had an extra `VALUES` keyword before the list of column names.